# How to extract an array from string input?

Tags: java

Input is in this format...

```
String input = "3 12#45#33 94#54#23 98#59#27";
```

To be extracted in this array...

```
int[][] array = new int[3][3];
```

Comment: *what* have you tried?

Comment: Sounds like you want to be using `String.split` and `Integer.parseInt`. Not sure what the need for the "3" at the start is though.

Comment: where are your efforts, you need to show something before you ask here for help.

Comment: @JonSkeet 3 there denotes the size of matrix....its a sample input

Comment: But isn't that clear from the fact that there are 3 space-separated parts following it, and then each part has 3 hash-separated parts?

Comment: @JonSkeet I'm guessing that that can vary. E.g. `"4 123#245#546#2 5#6#8#7"`

Comment: Even so, you can work out the size needed based on the number of elements provided.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can split the string and then iterate over the array. Which results in something like this:

```
String input = "3 12#45#33 94#54#23 98#59#27";
String[] strings = input.split(" ");

int size = Integer.parseInt(strings[0]);
int[][] result = new int[size][size];

for( int i = 0; i < strings.length - 1; i++ ){
    String[] strings2 = strings[i + 1].split("#");
    for( int j = 0; j < strings2.length; j++ ){
        result[i][j] = Integer.parseInt(strings2[j]); // add the parsed int to result
    }
}
```

Comment: 3 is size of array 3 X 3.

Comment: I'm surprised you answered considering your initial comment "*what have you tried*" :)

Comment: @notyou I'm guessing I got weak ;)